# Replace special characters on date columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with four columns two of them date, both yyyy-mm-dd and I need to bring them in select like yyyy / mm / dd

I tried something like that:

```
SELECT * REPLACE(*,'-','/') FROM table
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can use `*` inside a function like that, you need to list each of the columns explicitly.

Comment: `DATE` columns do not contain "special" characters. In fact they don't contain "characters" at all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need formatting your date, instead of "replace special chars". Use `to_char` function to do it:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE, to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

More [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).